# Identify shower brand (circle with two lines inside)

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

I'm trying to identify this shower brand to replace a cartridge. There are no other markers on the shower except a symbol at the front. The symbol is a circle with two vertical lines in the middle, the left hand line leaning forward.

Is anyone able to identify it and point me in the direction of spares? It was installed around ten years ago. Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: logo of shower]

[image: full shower view]

Comment: What country is this in?  Many brands are regional.

Comment: https://allthumbsdiy.com/plumbing/how-to-identify-a-faucet-brand.  This site offers some suggestions for identifying your faucet

Comment: I was in the plumbing supply business for a long time and am confident it is not a common American manufacturer. 10 years ago that style was almost always European made. Are you in the US?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please write up an answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.